# php pear Mail_mime wrong content-type text/html vs multipart/alternative vs multipart/related

Tags: php, email, pear, mail-mime

This same code works fine for other emails, just extra attachements.  Yet this "same" email code results in an email with `Content-Type: text/html...` so I can see all the multipart boundries showing in the email or in a multipart/related the html body gets turned into an attachement and the email is blank!

```
$emailHtml = "<h1>BLAH</h1>"
$emailTxt = "TEXT!"

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol'=>"\n"));

$mime->setHTMLBody($emailHtml, false);
$mime->setTxtBody($emailTxt, false);

$mime->headers(array(
  'From' => '"me" <example@example.com>',
  'Subject' => $subject
));
$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');

$mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
$mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8";
$mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8";
$mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8";
$mail->send($email, $mime->headers(), $mime->get($mimeparams));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the text portion was blank, which causes `Mail_mime` to go "insane" for lack of a better description.

Comment: Please open a bug report about this.

Comment: @cweiske bug report refused as I use an old PHP version (5.3.3) with the latest Mail_mime version 1.10.0.

Comment: latest mail_mime is enough.